# Finding the Centre of Gravity (Using Single Integral) of an Arc of the Astroid $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = a^{2/3}$ in the First Quadrant

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**My Attempted Solution:** First off, the curve will intersect the x and y axis at $(a, 0)$ and $(0, a)$. We can also rewrite the function: $y = (a^{2/3}-x^{2/3})^{3/2}$. To find the y-coordinate of the centre of mass the equation is : $\frac{\int y_{avg} \ dm}{\int dm}$. For our purposes, since we are working with a line (arc length) we can rewrite the equation to $$y_{cm} =\frac{\int y \ dl}{\int dl}$$ in other words, the $y$ value at $dl$ divided by the total arc length. Now, I need to relate $dl$ to $x$ in order to solve the integrals. By definition we know that a small arc length can be calculated by:

$$dl = \sqrt{1+y'^{2}}dx = \sqrt{1 + [\frac{3}{2}(a^{2/3}-x^{2/3})^{1/2}(-\frac{2}{3}x^{-1/3})]^2} dx = \sqrt{ 1+ [(a^{2/3}-x^{2/3})x^{-2/3}]} \ dx = \sqrt{(\frac{a}{x})^{2/3}} \ dx = (\frac{a}{x})^{1/3} \ dx$$.

Hence the top part of the $y_{cm}$ can be written as $\int_{0}^{a} (a^{2/3} - x^{2/3})^{3/2}(\frac{a}{x})^{1/3} dx$. Which when put through a calculator produces and answer of $\frac{3}{5}a^2$. Furthermore, the length of this arc is $\frac{3}{2}a$. When you divide the two values you get $\frac{2}{5}a$. Is this correct?

Comment: You should be able to solve the integral by hand(no calculator necessary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cleaner approach is to let $ x = a\cos^3t$ and $y=a\sin^3t$. Then, $dl = \sqrt{(x_t’)^2+(y_t’)^2} dt = 3a\sin t\cos t dt$ and

$$y_c = \frac{\int y \ dl}{\int dl}
= \frac{\int_0^{\pi/2} a\sin^3t\cdot 3a\sin t\cos t dt}{\int_0^{\pi/2} 3a\sin t\cos t dt}
=\frac{\frac35 a^2}{\frac32a}= \frac25 a
$$